# Not getting Consumer output while executing in ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am a newbie to Kafka. While trying some hands on, I am facing two problems.It would be of great help if someone could advise how to understand this.

When I am running Kafka from Eclipse, when I run my Producer Code, I am able to see what I sending to the Kafka Broker by running the consumer script from console *'kafka-console-consumer.sh'* . However, when I am running the Consumer script from Eclipse, I am not able to see anything on the Eclipse Console. Here is the Consumer Code I am running in Eclipse. IN my Producer Code, I had just sent a **Value** (a String) to the same topic as shown in the Consumer script. I am unable to see the same **Value** when I am doing a "Run as Java Application" on the  Consumer Script.

```
public class SimpleConsumer  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String topicName = "SimpleProducerTopic";
        String groupName = "SimpleGroup";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", groupName);
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
        while(true)
        {
            ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumer.poll(2);
            for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> rec : records)
            {
                System.out.println("Value :" + String.valueOf(rec.value()));
            }
        }
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

The second thing I am having a doubt about is : 
In the producer, when I am sending some data, that gets accumulated in the broker and every time I execute my consumer script, I am getting a cumulative result. However I want something like this :

First Execution :

- Sending " Hello" from Producer
- Rcvng " Hello" at Consumer

Second Execution :

- Sending " Hello Hello" from Producer
- Rcvng " Hello Hello" at Consumer

But what I am getting is :

First Execution :

- Sending " Hello" from Producer
- Rcvng " Hello" at Consumer

Second Execution :

- Sending " Hello Hello" from Producer
- Rcvng " Hello Hello Hello" at Consumer .

I checked a resources on Quora that one way to deal with this is reduce the time your data persists from configs. However, since that it is not a good practice, I was wondering if there is a way how I can prevent consumer from consuming  what it already consumed in its last poll.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first problem, make sure that `topicName`, `groupName` and `bootstrap.servers` are set properly. Also `String.valueOf(rec.value())` is redundant, since `rec.value()` is already has type `String`.

Regarding the second problem, do you set the same group for both "executions" when start console consumer (`--consumer-property group.id=your_group`)? If not, then each new execution will create a new group, which will read topic from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for our help with the second solution. I will try that. However, the first one is not solved despite those parameters being correctly set.